# Jackson Object Mapper Versioned issue from Java 7 to Java 8

Tags: java, jackson, java-8, upgrade

I am trying to upgrade Java version from `1.7` to `1.8`.
Didn't change any code apart from upgrading target version to 1.8 in Maven plugin.

`Error: cannot access Versioned`.

Source:

```
private ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
return mapper.writeValueAsString(data);
```

Couldn't find any documentation anywhere in the internet. I thought `1.8` should be completely backward compatible.

**Edit**:
Without even changing pom, if I set my local maven to Java 8, it's still breaking. So compiling with Java 8 is having issue :(

```
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.2.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-core-asl:jar:1.1.0:compile
[INFO] +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.2.2:compile
[INFO] +- com.fasterxml:jackson-xml-databind:jar:0.6.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:jar:1.9.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-xc:jar:1.9.2:compile
[INFO] +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.2.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.2.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-core-asl:jar:1.1.0:compile
[INFO] +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.2.2:compile
[INFO] +- com.fasterxml:jackson-xml-databind:jar:0.6.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:jar:1.9.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-xc:jar:1.9.2:compile
[INFO] +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.2.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.2.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-core-asl:jar:1.1.0:compile
[INFO] +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.2.2:compile
[INFO] +- com.fasterxml:jackson-xml-databind:jar:0.6.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:jar:1.9.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-xc:jar:1.9.2:compile
[INFO] +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.2.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.2.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-core-asl:jar:1.1.0:compile
[INFO] +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.2.2:compile
[INFO] +- com.fasterxml:jackson-xml-databind:jar:0.6.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:jar:1.9.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-xc:jar:1.9.2:compile
[INFO] +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.2.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.2.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-core-asl:jar:1.1.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-jaxrs:jar:1.9.11:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:jar:1.9.11:compile
[INFO] +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.2.2:compile
[INFO] +- com.fasterxml:jackson-xml-databind:jar:0.6.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-xc:jar:1.9.2:compile
[INFO] +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.2.2:compile
[INFO] +- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-core-asl:jar:1.9.13:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-jaxrs:jar:1.9.11:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.6.0-rc2:compile
[INFO] +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.2.2:compile
[INFO] +- com.fasterxml:jackson-xml-databind:jar:0.6.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:jar:1.9.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-xc:jar:1.9.2:compile
[INFO] +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.2.2:compile
```

-X output:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) on project my-module: Compilation failure
[ERROR] /Users/xxxxxx/MyApp.java:[52,15] error: cannot access Versioned
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) on project myntra-orch-lms: Compilation failure
/Users/xxxxxx/MyApp.java:[52,15] error: cannot access Versioned

    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:212)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:862)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:286)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:197)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.CompilationFailureException: Compilation failure
/Users/xxxxxx/MyApp.java:[52,15] error: cannot access Versioned

    at org.apache.maven.plugin.AbstractCompilerMojo.execute(AbstractCompilerMojo.java:656)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.CompilerMojo.execute(CompilerMojo.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
    ... 20 more
[ERROR]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

Comment: Hmm, shouldn't you [open an issue](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/issues) instead?

Comment: @fge, I am not sure whether it's Jackson issue or some other genuine issue which I am not aware. It's better to know before I raise issue

Comment: Well, to me it definitely sounds like a bug. As you say, there is no reason why updating the JDK would cause your code to fail. But that's your decision, of course ;)

Comment: I can relate my own experience that Jackson works fine for me with Java 7 and 8 both. Do you have some sort of version conflict with jackson-core vs other jackson libraries? Which Jackson version are you using?

Comment: @araqnid,  it shouldn't matter as changing JDK doesn't need to change libraries unless you are downgrading

Comment: Can show the full compiler error message? Can you run `mvn dependency:tree | grep jackson` to show the version of Jackson libraries in your classpath.

Comment: @AlexeyGavrilov, I updated the op

Comment: @AlexeyGavrilov, `[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) on project xxxxxxxxx: Compilation failure
[ERROR] /Users/xxxxxxxxxx/MessagingApp.java:[52,15] error: cannot access Versioned`

Comment: What is on the MessagingApp.java:[52,15] ?

Comment: @AlexeyGavrilov, `mapper.writeValueAsString(data)`

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are using a mix of very old Jackson versions. I suspect that in Java 8 the order of the .jar files used by the Maven compiler plugin can be different then in Java 7 so the `Versioned` interface may not be found. It can be an issue since in Java 8 the java compiler requires the interface to be present in the classpath when compiling the implementation ([JDK-8055048](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8055048)).

The `Versioned` interface was introduced in 1.6.0 while you have the `org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-core-asl` version 1.1.0. That is probably the root cause of the the problem.

A low risk fix could be to bump the `org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-core-asl` version to 1.9.2 to correspond the other libraries by adding the following dependency in the .pom file:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.2</version>
</dependency>
```

As a long term solution I suggest to consider bumping the Jackson version to the latest 2.X (packaged in `com.fastxml.jackson`) in all your projects and stop using version 1.X (packaged in `org.codehaus.jackson`).

Comment: Gavirolv, let me know how can I help you resolve this. It's bit huge project and -X prints lot of log. Anything specific you are looking for? Though I didn't understand how changing Java version can cause this issue? It's happening in `another project also`. Same error where we are using `mapper.writeValueAsString(entry);`

Comment: @Reddy I have updated my answer. Let's see if it helps.